# What shape should Unity app icons be and which icons are necessary?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, icons

I am making a app for iOS and Android and have a couple questions about the icons. First I know I should make Android icons a square because the launcher cuts it into shape. Does iOS do the same or do I need to have the icon in the proper shape? If I have to add the shape on my own what would the border radius's for each size be? Second do I need to use the adaptive icons with 2 layers or will my app still work on those devices using the other icons?

Answer (score 1):

For android the app icon size 512 is recommended

For iOS the app icon size 2048 is recommended

Unity is capable to generate other size what all are required.
You can use this online tool to generate all size app icon

https://makeappicon.com/

It will create shape for iOS too that is 180 radius for corner as iOS do not support alpha in app icon, for android you can use square or with alpha corner, both is ok.